# Running couchdb view with group=false (SELECT DISTINCT type behavior)

Tags: couchdb

I was following this guide on couchdb http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html#unique in order to return a `distinct` list from a view.

My map function looks like:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.PartnerName !=null) {
    emit(doc.PartnerName, null);
  }
}
```

And, I have a reduce function:

```
function(keys, values) {
  return true;
}
```

When I run this by hitting:

> /dbName/_design/Partners/_view/my-view-name

I get this back:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":true}
]}
```

If I add `?reduce=false` to the end, I get back *sort of* the desired result:

```
{
  "total_rows":11,"offset":0, 
  "rows":[
    {"id":"a","key":"PARTNER_ONE","value":null},
    {"id":"b","key":"PARTNER_ONE","value":null},
    {"id":"c","key":"PARTNER_ONE","value":null},
    {"id":"d","key":"PARTNER_ONE","value":null},
    {"id":"e","key":"PARTNER_ONE","value":null},
    {"id":"f","key":"PARTNER_ONE","value":null},
    {"id":"g","key":"PARTNER_TWO","value":null},
    {"id":"h","key":"PARTNER_TWO","value":null},
    {"id":"i","key":"PARTNER_TWO","value":null},
    {"id":"j","key":"PARTNER_THREE","value":null},
    {"id":"k","key":"PARTNER_FOUR","value":null}
]}
```

However, I'm ideally trying to get a distinct list, so in the above example, it'd be PARTNER_ONE, PARTNER_TWO, PARTNER_THREE, PARTNER_FOUR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `group=true` parameter. Try to query

```
/dbName/_design/Partners/_view/my-view-name?group=true
```

and see if that gives you the correct result.